# In what way is gobject facilitating binding?

Tags: gobject, gobject-introspection

On [the official website of gobject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/chapter-intro.html), we can read:

> GObject, and its lower-level type system, GType, are used by GTK+ and most GNOME libraries to provide:
>
> - object-oriented C-based APIs and
> - automatic transparent API bindings to other compiled or interpreted
>   languages

The first part seems clear to me but not the second one.

Indeed, when talking about gobject and binding, the concept introduced is often gobject-intropspection, but as far as I understand, gobject-introspection can be used to create .gir and .typelib for any documented C library, not only for gobject-based library.

Therefore I wonder what makes gobject particularly binding-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as far as I understand, gobject-introspection can be used to create .gir and .typelib for any documented C library, not only for gobject-based library.

That's not really true in practice.  You can do some very basic stuff, but you have to write the GIR by hand (instead of just running a program which scans the source code).  The only ones I'm aware of are [those distributed with gobject-introspection](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gobject-introspection/tree/gir) (the *.gir files, the *.c files there are to avoid cyclical dependencies), and even those are generally only a fairly small subset of the C API.

As for other features, almost everything in GObject helps… the basic idea is that bindings often need RTTI.  There are types like `GValue` (a simple box to store a value + type information), `GClosure` (for callbacks), properties and signals describe themselves with `GType`s, *etc*.  If you use GObjects (instead of creating a new fundamental type) you get run-time data about inheritance and interfaces, and GObject's odd construction scheme even allows other languages to subclass types declared in C.

The reason `g-ir-scanner` can't really do much on non-GObject libraries is that all that information is missing.  After scanning the source code looking for annotations, `g-ir-scanner` will actually load the compiled module and use GObject's API to grab this information (which makes cross-compiling painful).  In other words, GObject-Introspection is a much smaller project than you think… a huge percentage of the data it needs it gets from the GObject API.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that `g-ir-scanner` was using GObject this way. As for RTTI, is this really useful for a non-interpreted language ? It is used successfully in PyGObject for instance, but does it make sense in a compiled language ?

Comment: This makes more sense if you s/interpreted/dynamically typed/.  But the answer is yes; it's definitely *more* useful when you don't have static type information, but there are lots of cases in C where you can avoid rewriting the same code over and over by using something like GValue, or adding a GType parameter.

Comment: Could you give an example illustrating your last sentence please ?

Comment: The first one which comes to mind, I don't know why, is APIs like prepared statements for databases, or parsing data formats (think json).  Wouldn't you like to avoid having a set_int, set_uint(unsigned int value), set_double(double), set_string(char*), set_data(uint8_t*), etc. for every level of your API, or would you rather just have a single set_value(GValue* value)?  How about something like GBinding (https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/GBinding.html)?  If you're familiar with languages with generics or templates, basically any time you would use one of those.